# BibLaTeX – Cite as "Author et al. (Conference abbrev - year)"

Tags: biblatex, biber

I’m trying to get biblatex (which I use with biber) to produce citations like follows when citing conference proceedings

```
Authors (CONF name abbreviation - date)
```

For example, [this paper](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/sohl-dickstein15.html) shourd get cited as (in text)

```
Sohl-Dickstein et al. (ICML 2015)
```

Is there a standard way to do that? I suppose I could take advantage of the `eventtitle` bibtex field, is that what it is meant for?

---

Stripped down example of my use-case:

```latex
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,]{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./resources/bibliography.bib}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\textcite{sohl-dicksteinDeepUnsupervisedLearning2015}}
Some explanations on that paper
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Current bibtex file:

```
@inproceedings{sohl-dicksteinDeepUnsupervisedLearning2015,
  title = {Deep {{Unsupervised Learning}} Using {{Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics}}},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 32nd {{International Conference}} on {{Machine Learning}}},
  author = {{Sohl-Dickstein}, Jascha and Weiss, Eric and Maheswaranathan, Niru and Ganguli, Surya},
  year = {2015},
  month = jun,
  pages = {2256--2265},
  publisher = {{PMLR}},
  issn = {1938-7228},
  urldate = {2023-01-07},
  langid = {english},
}
```

Expected output:

- one frame whose title is "Sohl-Dickstein et al. (ICML 2015)
  " (ICML stands for International Conference on Machine Learning)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a minimal example? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography In particular, with which style are you loading `biblatex`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX on it (for the minimal example). I’m currently loading `biblatex` with `backend=biber,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=ynt`. But I guess I’d have to change that? I’m not really familiar with citation styles

Comment: @Nephanth See my answer, you don't need to use the `filecontents*` environment, you already have your `bibliography.bib` file, I had to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own cite command (`\citeconf` in my example), adding `shorttitle={ICML}` in your bibitem:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@inproceedings{sohl-dicksteinDeepUnsupervisedLearning2015,
  title = {Deep {{Unsupervised Learning}} Using {{Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics}}},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 32nd {{International Conference}} on {{Machine Learning}}},
  shorttitle={ICML},
  author = {{Sohl-Dickstein}, Jascha and Weiss, Eric and Maheswaranathan, Niru and Ganguli, Surya},
  year = {2015},
  month = jun,
  pages = {2256--2265},
  publisher = {{PMLR}},
  issn = {1938-7228},
  urldate = {2023-01-07},
  langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,]{beamer}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeconf}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}% 
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\printnames{labelname}
   \mkbibparens{%
     \printfield{shorttitle}%
     \addspace%
     \printfield{year}%
   }%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
  
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\citeconf{sohl-dicksteinDeepUnsupervisedLearning2015}}
Some explanations on that paper
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up basing my solution on yours, but using the `eventtitle` field instead of `shorttitle`, and applying a biber map to work out the abbreviations

Comment: @Nephanth You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!